# Installing Hudson remotely?

Tags: hudson, java, cpanel

I'm trying to install Hudson on a server. The article [here](http://weblogs.java.net/blog/kohsuke/archive/2007/02/hudson_became_s.html) says to just do `java -jar hudson.war` and it should install to the server. This is pretty straightforward to do on a local computer, but I want to do it on a remote website host that I manage via cPanel. So how on earth do I do this? I really am a newb when it comes to this sort of thing...

Also, obviously I require the JRE to do this. How do you install the JRE on a remote website host via cPanel? I don't even know where to get started...

Thanks.

Comment: This may help. You need SSH access to the hosting.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2746113/installing-hudson-remotely

Answer (score 2):

Short answer: get a VPS.  If you don't have shell access you're in for a world of frustration here.

Answer (score 1):

You will not be allowed to do this, NEVER!

No Seriously you wont

:-)